# How to find the closest time to the current time from an array using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array of values `[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1260]`. Each array item describes the number of minutes after midnight UTC.

Using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), how can I find the array item closest to the current `'Europe/London'` time?

So far I have been able to get the current `'Europe/London'` time using [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
var currentTime = moment().tz('Europe/London');
```

But am now struggling to find the closest array item to `currentTime`.

Comment: What did you try so far? Combining array reduce with moment's distance functions seems like a straightforward path to take.

Comment: Why are you getting the time in a particular timezone and comparing it against UTC? The "current [zone] time" is no different from the time anywhere else, until you format it.

Comment: @ssube a) I have JSON values in UTC (I can't help that, it's just what I'm getting from my API call). b) My website needs to display times in Europe/London time for all, regardless of your computers system clock or where you are in the world.

Comment: @henrywright Compare UTC to UTC, then format into the timezone at the very end. Ideally, all of your business logic would operate in UTC, allowing the client (whatever it may be) to format as part of the view logic or even template.

Comment: @ssube thanks for the heads up. I'll modify my code so that `currentTime` is in UTC and then format at the end like you suggest. I'm still stuck on the next part though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at all possible, you should keep the value in UTC until you're ready to format. Timezone, along with date format, is generally part of localization and not something you want embedded too deeply in your business logic. Do note that there have been timezones that changed their local flow of time, which is a nightmare for everyone.

With your incoming data and comparison data both in UTC, you can simply sort the array by absolute difference:

```js
var now = moment.utc();
var target = now.hours() * 60 + now.minutes();
var data = [180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1260]

var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var dA = Math.abs(a - target),
    dB = Math.abs(b - target);
  if (dA < dB) {
    return -1;
  } else if (dA > dB) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

The first element will then be the closest, followed by the rest by order of distance.

Comment: after what you said about UTC, should you be using `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var x= [180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1260]

closestTime=500
var newar=[]

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
newar.push(Math.abs(closestTime-x[i]))
}

var i = newar.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, newar));
console.log(x[i])
```